# Align UINavigationBar title with button on the right like iOS13 Messages app

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

What is the best way to align right bar button items with left title in `UINavigationBar` ? 
(now I have the icons at the top right corner)
[image]

Comment: Hello @Zac, I'm facing the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no @Zept

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is a more correct and optimal solution, but it is suitable for me.
Do not be alarmed by the syntax, I use [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit)

1. Create button or view

```
lazy private var settingsButton = UIButton().then {
        $0.setImage(Image.settings, for: .normal)
    }
```

2. override `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.forEach { subview in
    let stringFromClass = NSStringFromClass(subview.classForCoder)
    guard stringFromClass.contains("UINavigationBarLargeTitleView") else { return }
    subview.subviews.forEach { label in
        guard label is UILabel else { return }
        subview.addSubview(settingsButton)
        settingsButton.snp.makeConstraints{
            $0.top.equalTo(label)
            $0.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-14)
            $0.height.width.equalTo(35)
        }
    }
}
```

3. set `UIScrollViewDelegate` and in `scrollViewDidScroll` method get ahead of the `navigationBar` state and then hide / show the `UIBarButtonItem`

#### Result

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpMv3.jpg)